# Send curly brackets in URLSession httpBody

Tags: json, swift, http, post

I need to make a POST request using URLSession and send the exact JSON below as httpBody.
My problem is correctly sending curly and square brackets.

```
{
  "confirm": true,
  "booking": [
    {
      "sendSms": false,
      "order": "8724897",
      "priority": 2,
      "phone": {
        "description": "Main phone",
        "number": "555444333"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is what I'm using and it doesn't work as it is always sending square brackets instead of curly ones.
I guess it is sending arrays and not objects.

```
let phone = [String:Any]()
    phone["description"] = "Main phone" 
    phone["number"] = "555444333"

let booking = [String:Any]()  
    booking["sendSms"] = false
    booking["order"] = "8724897"
    booking["priority"] = 2
    booking["phone"] = phone

let json = [String:Any]()
    json["confirm"] = true
    json["booking"] = [booking]
```

Here down how it is sent

```
let bodyData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
request.httpBody = bodyData
```

What do you suggest?
Thanks

Comment: Add the code where you're setting the http body using that dictionary

Comment: When you say “My problem is correctly sending curly and square brackets”, what do you mean? Using `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options:)` (as you’ve included in your revised question) does that for you. Why do you think there is a problem with the curly/square brackets? Just look at `String(data: bodyData, encoding: .utf8)!` and you’ll see that everything is fine.

Comment: Unrelated, but did you really mean to send an array of bookings with the confirmation? Or did you mean `json["booking"] = booking`?

Comment: All the brackets the server is receiving are square.

Comment: “All the brackets the server is receiving are square.” No, look at the `String(data: bodyData, encoding: .utf8)!` and you can clearly see that the only square brackets are around your array of bookings, which I’m wondering if you really meant to be a single booking, not an array of them.

Comment: booking is an array of objects but only contains one item. The exact JSON structure is above in the main question.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if your server is complaining about the presence of square brackets, that array is the only pair of square bracket that is there. And given the key name is `booking`, not `bookings`, I am wondering whether it really is expecting an array with one item in it, but maybe is just expecting the booking dictionary with only the curly braces. It’s impossible to say on the basis of the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize `json`, e.g. with `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options)`:

E.g.

```
let phone: [String: Any] = [
    "description": "Main phone",
    "number": "555444333"
]

let booking: [String: Any] = [
    "sendSms": false,
    "order": "8724897",
    "priority": 2,
    "phone": phone
]

let json: [String: Any] = [
    "confirm": true,
    "booking": [booking]
]

do {     
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Or you could use `Codable` types and then use `JSONEncoder`:

```
struct Phone: Codable {
    let description: String
    let number: String
}

struct Booking: Codable {
    let sendSms: Bool
    let order: String
    let priority: Int
    let phone: Phone
}

struct Bookings: Codable {
    let confirm: Bool
    let booking: [Booking]
}

let phone = Phone(description: "Main phone", number: "555444333")
let booking = Booking(sendSms: false, order: "8724897", priority: 2, phone: phone)
let bookings = Bookings(confirm: true, booking: [booking])

do {     
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(bookings)
    ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

You say that the server is expecting JSON in the following form:

```
{
  "confirm": true,
  "booking": [
    {
      "sendSms": false,
      "order": "8724897",
      "priority": 2,
      "phone": {
        "description": "Main phone",
        "number": "555444333"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That is what the above will generate. The `booking` key is an array (with square brackets) with only one item in it.

But you also suggest that the server is complaining about square brackets. I’m wonder if the server might actually be expecting a simple dictionary, e.g.

```
{
  "confirm": true,
  "booking": {
    "sendSms": false,
    "order": "8724897",
    "priority": 2,
    "phone": {
      "description": "Main phone",
      "number": "555444333"
    }
  }
}
```

If the `booking` is always only a single item, this would be a more customary format. In that case, the code would be:

```
let phone: [String: Any] = [
    "description": "Main phone",
    "number": "555444333"
]

let booking: [String: Any] = [
    "sendSms": false,
    "order": "8724897",
    "priority": 2,
    "phone": phone
]

let json: [String: Any] = [
    "confirm": true,
    "booking": booking   // note, not an array, but single item
]

do {     
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or

```
struct Phone: Codable {
    let description: String
    let number: String
}

struct Booking: Codable {
    let sendSms: Bool
    let order: String
    let priority: Int
    let phone: Phone
}

struct Confirmation: Codable {
    let confirm: Bool
    let booking: Booking
}

let phone = Phone(description: "Main phone", number: "555444333")
let booking = Booking(sendSms: false, order: "8724897", priority: 2, phone: phone)
let confirmation = Confirmation(confirm: true, booking: booking)

do {     
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(confirmation)
    ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hello Rob, thanks a lot! Looks like the issue was not in the request body.
Unrelated, would you suggest using structs of codables?

Comment: In general, yes, but use whatever you want. But we like `Codable` types because it enforces the key names, making it harder to end up with typos in keys that are easily introduced when manually building dictionaries.